# Как в React после события onMouseDown над элементом повесить на этот же объект событие onMouseMove?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouse-event

Если более детально хочу реализовать перетаскивание блоков

```
onMouseDown={(e) => {
    //Повесить на блок событие onMouseMove в котором менять координаты 
}}
onMouseUp={(e) => {
    //Убрать событие onMouseMove
    //Отправить изменения на сервер
    //В случае rejected вернуть на место и сообщить об ошибке
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я кажется пошёл не тем путём!

1. Надо установить глобальную переменную moving
2. При onMouseDown менять её на true
3. При onMouseUp менять на false
4. Повесить на элемент onMouseMove код к котором обернуть в if(moving){
   do something
   }